# JSON Parse Error works on localhost but not work on live godaddy domain

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","secret","secret","quakealert");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

     if(isset($_POST['id'])){

        $id  = $_POST['id'];
        $name = areaName($id);
        $data = statsReport($name);
        //sleep(3);
        echo json_encode($data);
        //echo $data;
     }

     if(isset($_POST['idd'])){

        $id  = $_POST['idd'];


        $name = areaName($id);

        $data = UpdateChart($name);

        echo json_encode($data);
     }

     function areaName($id){

        $query = "SELECT area_name FROM `location_details` WHERE `Location_ID`='".$id."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$query);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        return $data[0];
     }

     function statsReport($name){

         $query  = "(SELECT * FROM `".$name."` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4) ORDER BY id ASC";

         $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$query);

         $results_array = array();

         while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
         {
            $results_array[] = $row;
         }

         return $results_array;

     }
?>
```

This is my output of the PHP script which is valid JSON:

```
[{"id":"12","current_value":"3.6","last_value":"3","inputTime":"2016-08-10 17:16:02","updateTime":"2016-08-10 14:46:11","updateCheck":"1"}]
```

My PHP Script:

```
<script>
  var ajaxCall = function(area_id){

      return $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.php",
     //dataType: 'application/json',

      data:({id:area_id}),

    });
    }
 var clifton  = ajaxCall(3);
    var defence  = ajaxCall(1);

    //parse the data of ajax and through it into chart show

    clifton.success(function(data){
        //alert(data[0][1]);

        var testing  = $.parseJSON(data);//SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
      //data = JSON.parse(data);i tried this also

      chartShow(testing,"clifton",3);

    });

    defence.success(function(data){
     // data = JSON.parse(data);
      chartShow(data,"defence",1);

    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly fine on my localhost but when i upload it on godaddy domain it shows this error.

Comment: console.log(data) before you try to parse it, to verify that it is really valid JSON ....

Comment: try console.log(data) to view what return data from server

Comment: i am accessing my data varaible as data[0][1] and data[0][2] is it fine? if not so how should i get values inside in it